# Insert charater at left side of matching pattern using sed?

Tags: sed

Here is the data file as input.

```
1
2
2
979
data
raw
32j
23
32323
```

Output:

```
/* 1
/* 2
/* 2
/* 979
data
raw
/* 32j
/* 23
/* 32323
```

How I can get the desired OUTPUT using sed? Regex for matching pattern is **^[0-9]***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that what you want is to comment out lines starting with a number. That isn't what `^[0-9]*` means, that would match everything, including empty lines or lines with no numbers at all, because `*` means "0 or more" so it will match every line of your file.

So, to comment out lines that start with a number, you can use:

```
$ sed  '/^[0-9]/ s|^|/* |' file 
/* 1
/* 2
/* 2
/* 979
data
raw
/* 32j
/* 23
/* 32323
```

Or:

```
$ sed -E 's|^([0-9])|/* \1|' file 
/* 1
/* 2
/* 2
/* 979
data
raw
/* 32j
/* 23
/* 32323
```

Comment: thanks ... I am new to sed. can you give some good resources to learn and practice this tool.

Comment: @ujjwal_bansal start with `man sed` and also look at answers here, there are a lot of sed ones. Of course, searching for "sed tutorial" in your favorite search engine would also be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{$0="/* "$0}1' filename

/* 1
/* 2
/* 2
/* 979
data
raw
/* 32j
/* 23
/* 32323
```